# Iterate though ENV and write the result to a file in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to iterate through the EVN Hash and save the result into a file. Below is my attempt:

```
file "/srv/www/shared/test-create-file.txt" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
  tempVar = ""
  ENV.each_pair do |k, v| 
    tempVar = tempVar#{k}#{" = "}#{v}
  end
  content tempVar
  action "create"
end
```

The file is created but with an empty content. Could I get some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need to create a variable for that:

```
file "/srv/www/shared/test-create-file.txt" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
  content ENV.map { |k,v| "#{k} = #{v}" }.join("\n")
  action "create"
end
```

---

In case you just want to fix your iteration, try this instead:

```
ENV.each_pair do |k, v|
  tempVar = "#{tempVar}#{k} = #{v}\n"
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to create a temporary variable in this case. You can just pass the method directly into the `content` block as cassianoleal suggested.

However, I would strongly suggest moving to a `template` resource. You are performing data manipulation, which should really be left for a template:

```rb
template "/srv/www/shared/test-create-file.txt" do
  source "my-template.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0755"
  action "create"
end
```

And then in the template:

```
<% ENV.each do |key, value| %>
<%= key %>=<%= value %>
<% end %>
```

You can read more about the ERB templating language and Chef templates on the [Chef Docs](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_templates.html).

Comment: There is a typo <% end %> at the end, just to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

The hash (#) symbol in ruby is for making comments. Every thing after the hash (#) symbol on line 7 is being considered a comment.

In the each_pair block you are continually reassigning tempVar to tempVar. As tempVar is initially an empty String it is setting tempVar to an emptyString in each iteration.

Comment: This is totally true, but not the primary source of error in the OPs post. Nonetheless +1 because you're correct :)

Comment: The OP asks for hints about why the file is created with no content. I still see my answer is correct. Unless I am missing something (which is entirely possible)?

Comment: Sure, but the OPs answer will only create one ENV pair and it's clear that he really wants them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting `tempVar` to accumulate the return value from the `each_pair` block, you should consider using `inject`:

```
tempVar = {key1: :value1, key2: :value2}.inject('') do |memo, member| 
    memo += "#{member[0]} = #{member[1]}\n" 
end

# tempVar => "key1 = value1\nkey2 = value2\n"
```